# How can I prepend a common sequence of characters to a consequtive sequence of lines in Vim?

Tags: vim

Let's say I have the following:

```
foo bar bub
baz qux doo
```

And I want to end up with:

```
* foo bar bub
* baz qux doo
```

Is there any way short of `qqI* <Esc>jq3@q`, or using a macro? I can't imagine that there isn't. Thanks

Comment: And what's wrong with anatomy, now?

Answer (score 3):

`qqI* <Esc>jq3@q` *is* a macro.

- Another way:

  ```
  :,+norm I*<space><CR>
  ```

  (as benji commented, `,+` is a short notation for the `.,+1` range, meaning "from this line to the next one")
- Another way:

  ```
  :,+s/^/*<space><CR>
  ```
- Another way:

  ```
  <C-v>jI*<space><Esc>
  ```
- Another way:

  ```
  I*<space><Esc>j^*
  ```

Comment: The `,+` part in the first two options is a range, specifying two lines.  See `:help :range` for other options.  I often select several lines in Visual mode and then type `:`, which automatically inserts the range I have selected (using the `'<` and `'>` marks).

Comment: That <C-v> option is probably the best way. It uses "visual block" mode to do an insert on every line in the selection.